# Close only one socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I made a piece of software which acts like a socket server (dispatches packets between three nodes in a infrastructure). 
To make it simple I created three threads, one for each TCP socket (I know this is not optimal but for my purposes it was the simplest option and also the fastest), and everything is working great.
At server start, the three socket perform the usual initialization (getaddr, listen, bind, etc) and listen to three different ports; as I launch a client, the client properly connect and send/recv data.

The issue is that: whenever one client disconnects, even the other sockets are forcefully disconnected and rebooted, and this is kinda a problem.
I bet the suspicious code lies here (this is the routine launched from the thread):

```
void ManageSocket1( void )
{
    while( true )
    {
        Socket* socket = new Socket( 27016, "SocketName" );
        if( socket->CreateSocket() )
        {
            socket->StartCommunication();
        }
        socket->CloseSocket();
        delete socket;
    }
}

void ManageSocket2( void )
{
    // clone of ManageSocket1
}
```

CreateSocket() is the responsible of socket creation, while StartCommunication() recv/sends data; for these two methods there is no need to post code because it's a "common" tcp socket-opening code.
The ManageSocketX() are launched by threads in main() and never return to main() because of their nature.

That's CreateSocket():

```
int Socket::CreateSocket( void )
{
res = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2,2 ), &wsaData );

if( res != 0 ) 
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "WSAStartup failed" );
    return ERROR;
}
else
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "WSAStartup done" );
}

res = getaddrinfo( NULL, socketPort, &hints, &result );

if ( res != 0 ) 
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "GetAddrInfo failed" );
    WSACleanup();
    return ERROR;
}
else
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "GetAddrInfo succesful");
}

ListenSocket = socket( result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol );

if( ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET ) 
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "GetAddrInfo failed with error: ", WSAGetLastError() );
    freeaddrinfo( result );
    WSACleanup();
    return ERROR;
}
else
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Socket created succesfully");
}

res = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, ( int )result->ai_addrlen );
if( res == SOCKET_ERROR ) 
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Bind failed with error: ", WSAGetLastError() );
    freeaddrinfo( result );
    closesocket( ListenSocket );
    WSACleanup();
    return ERROR;
}
else
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Socket successfully bound");
}

freeaddrinfo( result );

if( listen( ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) 
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Bind failed with error: ", WSAGetLastError() );     
    closesocket( ListenSocket );
    WSACleanup();
    return ERROR;
}
else
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Listening on port", atoi( socketPort ) );
}

ClientSocket = accept( ListenSocket, NULL, NULL );
if( ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET ) 
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Accept failed:", WSAGetLastError() );
    closesocket( ListenSocket );
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
else
{
    logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Client connection accepted" );
}

return SUCCESS;
}
```

and that's StartCom()

```
void Socket::StartCommunication( void )
{
char recvbuf[BUFLEN];
int  recvbuflen = BUFLEN;

do
{
    res = recv( ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0 );
    if( res > 0 ) 
    {
        logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Bytes received:", res );            
    } 
    else if( res == 0 )
    {
        logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Connection closing..." );
    }
    else 
    {
        logBook->PrintMsg( socketName, "Receive failed:", WSAGetLastError() );
        closesocket( ClientSocket );
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }       
} 
while( res > 0 );
}
```

Comment: When you say "clone of ManageSocket1", do you mean even in the port number? If so, then there's your problem.

Comment: I wrongly have not specified that; however, not: the sockets are open against three different ports.

Comment: I don't think the other sockets are closed by closing one of them. But maybe the remote end (the client) is closing all 3?

Comment: To be honest I left the c# close the socket (I'm kinda newb to c#), and really I do not know what is currently doing when I hit the Close button, but I'm pretty sure it does not call the object destructors where I placed the mySocket.Close() instruction. 
However, even whether the client submits wrong instructions to the server, the sockets in the server lie in three different threads, so that's kinda a strange beahviour

Comment: Does a single C# client open three connection to your C++ server? And you're closing that C# program?

Comment: Nope. A single client opens one connection against the server. Each client opens only one connection, and each on its unique port. 
Yes, I'm closing the c# client.

Comment: Please show the code for your Socket class. The bug lies within that code, not what you posted.

Comment: added significative code to the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `WSACleanup` when any of the sockets terminates. From the documentation:

> In a multithreaded environment, WSACleanup terminates Windows Sockets operations for all threads.

Further:

> Sockets that were open when WSACleanup was called are reset and automatically deallocated as if closesocket were called.

Comment: Well, that seemed to fix the issue, but without the WSACleanup I can't re-open a socket to the same port while the CreateSocket() returns at bind()

Comment: WSAStartup belongs in the parent process. I don't think its a per-thread req. Also - move the 'bind' to the parent thread and start a child for each 'accepted' socket. You're kind of doing it inside out.